# Network latency on a multiplayer mobile game

Tags: networking, mobile, physics, coronasdk, multiplayer

We are using Corona SDK and its physics engine to move objects along a landscape of some sort (like Tiny Wings) and we have a question regarding correction of positions. Say that a box is traveling along the rolling hills, but its position is computed on another device. A few times each second, you receive:

- an updated position
- the velocity of the box
- the time at which the information was sent

So we know that the information is X milliseconds old, and would like to find out where it should be by now (assuming it is affected by physics) and keep simulating until we get another update.
Right now, we tried simply multiplying the velocity by the amount of time since the package was sent, but as you can imagine, this behaves really poorly if the terrain is curved/not flat.

Is there a way to say: “Stop everything and give me the position this box would have if physics had acted on it for X ms, then resume gameplay” without actually halting all gameplay for X ms?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does "stop everything" mean if not to actually stop things?

Comment: I recommend http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/networked-physics/, especially the discussion of peer-to-peer networked physics in the comments

Comment: Yes, you can do a careful physics simulation to determine where the box probably is now, based on its state X ms ago, and display that. And you can extend the simulation the simulation as time passes, and adjust it whenever an update comes in. Does that answer your question, or do you need more?

Comment: @user964625 did you solve this? do the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

I donot know about Corona SDK but one way you can do this is to simulate your physics world for the duration of your game loop in each game loop. And when you receive the real position you can update your physics world.

Some physics engines may not be able to simulate larger time durations properly, hence it is advisable to do more number of smaller steps than one large step. So in your case donot do X ms each iteration, but smaller steps so you can get very accurate simulation.

One more thing over here is that the box movement may appear to jump when you receive the actual update, hence you may need to smoothen it out over few game loops.

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question 20 months ago, you probably have already solved this but I will just try to answer it for future visitors:

There is no one-best-way to solve this, there are always **correctness-latency tradeoffs**, however the following are some thoughts about it.

In principle there is no difference between networked physics and networked game-logic, it is both **networked synchronization**. We can try to abstract it to mean that there is some **event (space+time+state)** which all peers should agree on. That event could be a certain object-state calculated by a physics-engine or anything else.

You described that your packets contain a certain position and velocity (state) and timestamp at the time of event-initiation. Each peer tells other peers (direct or via server) what its **current** state is.

There is a way to do sync that works better (in my opinion): A peer should not tell what its current state is but instead tell what state it wants an object to have X milliseconds in the **future**.

The engine should try to make X be as close as possible to the sum of:

- the **observed latency** between clients
- a little **interpolation time**
- a little safety-margin

Note: it can find the **observed latency** by continually sending messages and analyzing the response-time

If the latency suddenly becomes worse and the safety-margin was not enough then there's a brief slowdown of the game until X was adapted.

The **simulation turns** are interleaved and each event gets **announced** beforehand so that every client can receive it, add it to its timeline then **interpolate-and-resolve** it when the time comes.

The simulation-turn that the X'th millisecond falls into can be called the target-turn.

(future readers: note that simulation-turns are often not identical to FPS, often they are much less frequent, e.g. every 10 frames or every 100ms or *and I like this the best* as fast as the network can deliver)

Example:

```
[Turn0] a client/physicsengine announces event e1
[Turn1] a client/physicsengine announces event e2
[Turn2] (other stuff)
[Turn3] (other stuff)
[Turn4] (other stuff)
[Turn5] clients start interpolating towards e1
[Turn6] clients start interpolating towards e2
[Turn7] e1 target-turn: e1 should be true/fulfilled now
[Turn8] e2 target-turn: e2 should be true/fulfilled now
[Turn9]
```

What to do if two **clients disagree** on what a certain event will be? First note that this can be detected by each client independently because each has a timeline where turns **become consistent before they are reached**. What is to do depends on your app and on what kind of event it is:

- There are many events that have **no gameplay-effect** e.g. if your physics engine calculated something that is only for nicer graphics. Those events can just be forgotten.
- For other events it would not matter if **one or the other version** is fulfilled as long as both clients agree. The clients can select the version decentrally (without the need for communication) based on some heuristic.
- In other cases it can occur that event A invalidates event B and B invalidates A: in that case you could **let the server decide and re-schedule** another X ms in the future.